# "Ambigous type variable" error when defining custom "read" function

Tags: haskell, serialization, typeclass

While trying to compile the following code, which is enhanced version of read build on readMay from Safe package.

```
readI :: (Typeable a, Read a) => String -> a
readI str = case readMay str of
               Just x -> x 
               Nothing -> error ("Prelude.read failed, expected type: " ++ 
                                 (show (typeOf > (undefined :: a))) ++ 
                                 "String was: " ++ str)
```

I get an error from GHC:

> WavefrontSimple.hs:54:81:
>           Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraint:
>            `Typeable a'
>              arising from a use of `typeOf' at src/WavefrontSimple.hs:54:81-103
>          Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)`

I don't understand why. What should be fixed to get what I meant?

**EDIT:** Ok, so the solution to use `ScopedTypeVariables` and `forall a` in type signature works. But why the following produces very similar error to the one above?  The compiler should infer the right type since there is `asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a` used.

```
readI :: (Typeable a, Read a) => String -> a
readI str = let xx = undefined in
            case readMay str of
              Just x -> x `asTypeOf` xx
              Nothing -> error ("Prelude.read failed, expected type: " 
                               ++ (show (typeOf xx)) ++ 
                                "String was: " ++ str)
```

Comment: I voted to close as dupe before the edit.  Now that the question has been updated, I believe it is no longer a duplicate, but can't remove the VTC.  I guess I'll just have to wait for it to expire on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter doesn't work because the type of `xx` is the same as the type of `undefined` -- i.e., "forall a. a." The fact that you force xx to be used with one concrete type with the asTypeOf operator doesn't mean that it is less polymorphic everywhere else.

Comment: I believe you are right. My understanding prior to your explanation was a bit different, and I yet have to change my thinking.

Answer (score 2):

The `a` in `undefined :: a` and `readI :: (Typeable a, Read a) => String -> a` are not the same *type* `a`.  It's as if you wrote `readI :: ... a; readI = ... (undefined :: b)`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

readI :: forall a. (Typeable a, Read a) => String -> a
...
```

The [scoped type variables](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables) extension changes the Haskell language to allow you to carry the *type variable* `a` from outer scope to inner scope, if explicitly quantified with `forall`.

---

I'm not sure why your `` x `asTypeOf` xx `` doesn't seem to work.  This does, though:

```
readI :: (Typeable a, Read a) => String -> a
readI str = xx where
    xx = case readMay str of
             Just x -> x
             Nothing -> error ("Prelude.read failed, expected type: "
                              ++ (show (typeOf xx)) ++
                               "String was: " ++ str)
```

Comment: This question may be a dupe but this is the best explanation I've seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need scoped type variables.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
readI :: forall a. (Typeable a, Read a) => String -> a
readI str = case readMay str of
               Just x -> x 
               Nothing -> error ("Prelude.read failed, expected type: " ++ 
                                 (show (typeOf > (undefined :: a))) ++ 
                                 "String was: " ++ str)
```

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713003/why-is-this-type-variable-ambiguous).

Comment: Whoops, I should have looked for duplicates first.  That's obviously one.

Comment: I did look for duplicates, apparently not hard enough. My bad.