# How can I give this sub-function an explicit type?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I have the following haskell code to expand environment variables in strings (parsing code omitted):

```
import Control.Monad (liftM)

data Token = Literal String | EnvReference String deriving Show

expandTokens :: (Monad m) => (String -> m (Maybe String)) -> [Token] -> m String
expandTokens getEnv toks = liftM concat (mapM toString toks) where
    toString (Literal s) = return s
    toString (EnvReference v) = liftM (maybe "" id) (getEnv v)
```

(it's intended to be used with an IO implementation of getEnv, but I figured it would be nicer for testing if it could be used with any monad)

When I was writing it, I tried to give the nested `toString` function an explicit type of:

```
toString :: Monad m => Token -> m String
```

But ghc says:

```
Sample.hs:8:58:
    Could not deduce (m ~ m1)
    from the context (Monad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 expandTokens :: Monad m =>
                                 (String -> m (Maybe String)) -> [Token] -> m String
( ... )
```

I get that the "Monad m" in the expandTokens must necessarily be the exact same `m` as in the type of `toString` (since it references the `getenv` of the containing function), but I can't figure out how to write an explicit type for `toString` which respects that - I don't think there's any way to refer to anything in a different type declaration, can it even be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this type variable ambiguous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713003/why-is-this-type-variable-ambiguous)

Comment: Ahh true - I didn't really know what to search for to find dupes. It is a different error message, but yeah it looks otherwise identical.

Comment: @dave4420: Same cause and solution, not really the same question, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`ScopedTypeVariables`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables). I've never used that, but it looks right.

Comment: That's the one, thanks! It then becomes: `expandTokens :: forall m . (Monad m) => (String -> m (Maybe String)) -> [Token] -> m String`

Comment: @gfxmonk: Also, note that the `Monad` constraint will be visible as well, so you don't need a constraint in `toString`'s type.